# Stuck understanding siblingIndex()

Tags: java, jsoup

i'm not sure if my head is just done for today but I'm actually stuck understanding siblingIndex() method in jsoup.

This is the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quote</th>
                    <th scope="col">Author</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I use siblingIndex() on `<table>` the output is 1. When I use siblingIndex() on `<thead>` its also 1. When I use elementSiblingIndex() the output is 0. The API reference says for siblingIndex(): "Get the list index of this node in its node sibling list. I.e. if this is the first node sibling, returns 0."

Ok. For `<thead>`, when node `<table>` would be first child node of parent node `<body>`, i would understand it. But node `<table>` has siblingIndex 1. `<tbody>` has siblingIndex 3. Could someone please explain to me how siblingIndex() works for this example? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you elborate how did you got that `table`'s index is 1 and `tbody` is 3?

Comment: A list of `Node`s (obtained with `childNodes()`)may be different that the list of `Element`s (obtained with `children()`). Try displaying and comparing both these lists to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **[siblingIndex()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#siblingIndex())** method counts [node children](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes()), which includes more things than just elements. The DOM tree contains nodes for elements (tags), text nodes (blank spaces in this case), and other node types like comments, data, etc.

The child node list for the `table` looks something like:

```
0: TextNode " "
1: Element thead
2: TextNode " "
3: Element tbody
4: TextNode " "
```

Unless you actually want to work with nodes, you probably want to use the **[elementSiblingIndex()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#elementSiblingIndex())** method. This method filters the `Node` list for `Element`s, and so the Element [children](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#children()) of `table` (which are Element siblings of each other) will be:

```
0: Element thead
1: Element tbody
```

I hope this helps clarify your understanding!